# How to detect a `Scene` (especially `Settings`) on disappear/close

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Here is the code fragment from [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settings)

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        #if os(macOS)
        Settings {
            SettingsView()
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

I followed the document to watch the `scenePhase` like this but got nothing

```swift
struct MyScene: Scene {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some Scene {
        Settings {
            SettingView()
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in
            print(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

I think that is because that `scenePhase` is the scenePhase of `MyApp`'s Scene. But how to get the `scenePhase` of `Settings`? Or how to detect `SettingView`'s on disappear?
Codes below are not working.

```swift
struct SettingView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some View {
        SomeView()
        .onAppear(perform: {
            print("setting view on appear") // only print once
        })
        .onDisappear {
            print("on disappear") // never print
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in
            print(newValue) // only print once
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, the `onChange(of: scenePhase)` should work - file a bug to Apple.